# Gfycat img tag inside webpage causes rest of the page (body onload) to not load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, twitter-bootstrap

So I got this webpage. It's basic html with an `<body onload="init();">`
Everything works fine. But now I try to put a Gfycat image in the webpage and nothing works.

I see the gyfcat but the rest of the page does not load it tells me :

```
http://localhost/mywebpage/true Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I don't have a "true" path nowhere in my directory and I don't reference it anywhere in my code either. At the moment I only want the image to show and the rest of my page to load but ultimately I would want to put the image inside my Bootstrap Carousel. The function init is never called as I put a breakpoint inside of it and it never was called.

The nav and everything that doesn't require js seems to load. But my body consists of a nav and a body. The body is a dhtmlx scheduler which is loaded in the init(). But like I said without the Gfycat img tag and script everything works perfectly. The script is provided on Gfycat's website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
<head>
   //a lot of metas links and scripts
 <script>
  (function(d, t) {
   var g = d.createElement(t),
       s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
   g.src = 'http://assets.gfycat.com/js/gfyajax-0.517d.js';
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
 }(document, 'script'));
 </script>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
 <img class="gfyitem" data-id="UniqueNiceCarp"/>
 //a lot of html
<body>
</html>
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: where is your `init` function?

Comment: in a main.js file. of course I have `<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> ` Like I wrote, everything works fine if I don't put the img and the gfy script.

Comment: There is something in the gfycat script that is causing this. Either that is wrong or you have implemented it incorrectly.

Comment: What happens if you try to include any other script instead of this gfycat? Does that also give you the same error?

Comment: When I do that it goes into the main.js loads the page, executes the gfycat function but the image doesn't show everything else is shown correctly. Actually the image tag is removed when I do inspect element in chrome. I'm very confused. I tried putting the img tag at different places but it is always removed.